# Implementation of Factory design pattern in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, protocols

I would like to implement the **factory design pattern** in **Swift 3.0**.

The basic solution that I am thinking of is:

- [Define a protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) that define as object creation method
- Implement the protocol within the Object

Is this a sound approach?

Or are there alternative design patterns in Swift?

Comment: Factory design pattern may be a sound approach, and there are a lot of alternative patterns aswell. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have got a server that returns JSON formatted data. I created a class with a method "createObjectType" to decouple the implementation of the class from the creation. The class contains also other methods (E.g. createMyObject2, createMyObject3). The idea is that each function can have different input parameters depending on the type of API version used (some API may return in a JSON format, some may use a different format).

Comment: In this case yes, your approach is good. You'll have one (or several) protocol(s) defining how the data must be formatted, and multiple implementations of those protocols (one for each endpoint for example). In order to know which implementation you have to use at a specific moment with a specific context / parameters, you can totally have a factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this implementation as a reference. 
https://redflowerinc.com/implementing-factory-design-pattern-in-swift/

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

enum Maps : Int {
    case google = 1
    case apple
}

protocol Display {
    func showMap()
}

class Map {
    let type : Int = 0
    func showMap(type : Maps) -> Display {
        switch type {
        case Maps.apple :
            return AppleMap()
        case Maps.google :
            fallthrough
        default:
            return GoogleMap()
        }
    }
}

class AppleMap : Display {
    func showMap() {
        print("showing apple map")
    }
}

class GoogleMap : Display {
    func showMap() {
        print("showing google map")
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view

        let map = Map()
        map.showMap(type: Maps.google)
        map.showMap(type: Maps.apple)
    }
}
```